# Transformation of binary data

Tags: data-transformation, optimization, binary-data

I have a function that I am trying to optimize using Particle Swarm Optimization.

The objective function gets a binary string. These binary strings are candidate solutions of the subject function. I can measure the dissimilarity between two solutions by the [Jaccard Coefficient](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaccard_index), but I need to move one solution towards another by a factor, meaning I need a vector.

Are there any methods to do that?

Example:

```
a = 0011001 
b = 0011010
```

I want to move `a` towards `b` by the factor of 0.4. So I need to find another string that is similarity between `a` is 0.6 and similarity between `b` is 0.4.

Actually strings are much longer. I am trying to somehow represent binary data n-dimensional space and then represent a vector from one point to another.

I hope I have explained myself clearly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your strings are sufficiently long, 
you can compute the weighted average of $a$ and $b$,
$c = (1-\lambda) a + \lambda b$,
interpret each value as a probability,
and sample according to those probabilities.

The result is only approximate, i.e.,
$ d(a,c) \approx \lambda d(a,b) $ 
and 
$ d(b,c) \approx (1-\lambda) d(a,b) $,
but that should be sufficient for your purposes.

```
n <- 1e4
a <- sample(c(TRUE,FALSE), n, replace=TRUE)
b <- sample(c(TRUE,FALSE), n, replace=TRUE)
lambda <- .1
jaccard <- function(a,b) sum( a & b ) / ( length(a) - sum( !a & !b ) )
distance <- function(a,b) 1 - jaccard(a,b)
distance(a,b)
x <- (1 - lambda) * a + lambda * b
x <- runif(n) < x
distance(a,x) / distance(a,b)  # Around lambda
distance(b,x) / distance(a,b)  # Around 1 - lambda
```

Another approach, to optimize discrete functions,
would be to use simulated annealing (you need to define a notion of "neighbouring string", 
e.g., one that only differs by one bit) or genetic algorithms 
(you need to define a notion of "crossover").